# How do I define macro that returns expressions to be used inside ->> macro?

Tags: clojure

I have function:

```
(defn parse-file [stream map-filter]  
  (->> (xml/parse stream)  
       (:content)  
       (func args1)  
       (func args2)  
       (func args3)  
       (attrs)))
```

I want that expressions with function named "func" were generated by macro.
Here it is:

```
(defmacro gen-macro [map-filter seq]
  `(~@(map #(list 'another-func % %2 seq) map-filter)))
```

But it returns `((func args1) (func args2) (func args2))`
How do i remove outer parentheses while generating expressions?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to splice the list resulting from `gen-macro` into the body of the `parse-file` function. Unless you turn `parse-file` into a macro as well, then you're not going to be able to splice syntax into its body.

However, you can still get the desired functionality. You just have to modify `gen-macro` a bit:

```
(defmacro gen-macro [map-filter seq]
  `(fn [x#] (->> x# ~@(map #(list 'another-func % %2) seq map-filter))))
```